# How do I symlink python to the osx default python?

Tags: python, macos, path, homebrew

Currently I use `conda` to manage my python installation, and I only installed `python3`.

```
$ which python
/Users/username/miniconda3/bin/python
$ which python3
/Users/username/miniconda3/bin/python3
```

So now both `python` and `python3` point to the same target:

```
$ python
Python 3.5.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:24:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
$ python3
Python 3.5.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:24:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I imagine this is probably not a very good idea and `brew doctor` also complained that

```
Warning: python is symlinked to python3
This will confuse build scripts and in general lead to subtle breakage.
```

So how can I point `python` to the osx system default python 2.x version?

Comment: IDK if this is the best way, but if `/Users/username/miniconda3/bin/python` is a symlink, deleting it would probably work.

Comment: have you tried modifying the `PATH` in the `.bash_profile`. I had the same problem because the Anaconda3 installer create this symlink.

Answer (score 2):

> Users/your_username/

Inside of it click: "Shift" + "Command" + "." (Show hidden files).
There is a file ".bash-profile" -> right click -> textedit .

Paste:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH
```

"Command" + "s". Now you have a symlink.